# How do I transform a layer in PhotoShop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to transform a layer specifically to resize the image or make the layer smaller but when I go to the edit on the tool bar I am unable to click on the transform tab to
resize it, is there another way to resize it? How can I make it so I can click on the transform tab?

Comment: To Resize you simply can use the CTRL+T Button. And to resize equally from all the side, use SHIFT key.

Answer (score 1):

In the Layers panel, click on the Background layer lock icon to convert it to a fully editable layer.  Now try *Edit > Transform*. It should work as expected.

[image]

After conversion to a normal layer (no longer a locked Background layer) it should look like this

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!!